# Car started then stopped. Now doesn't turn on or crank

Tags: ford, battery-drain, fusion, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2008 Ford Fusion S- battery is 3 years old but was still working without any issues. I hopped in the car this morning and started it up, mind you I had driven the car 24 hours prior. The car turned over almost caught to get the engine humming then turned off. Now the lights and electric locks won't work turn the key and nothing- no clicking, nada. I considered the battery (no jump cables, buying those today) some corrosion around the positive terminal, but what would cause a failure like this? I'm pretty good with cars but this has never happened in the six years I've owned this vehicle.

Comment: My guess is dead battery, caused by non functional alternator.   Or neutral safety switch not in exactly the right place. Try shifting thru gears then attempt to start the car in Neutral.